# Passing json object from grails controller to a gsp rendering a d3 chart?

Tags: grails, view, charts, controller, d3.js

I'm creating a d3 chart using a json object created in a grails controller..At the moment I'm passing the json to the view as a string which does't seem to be the best approach.

d3 provides a method to pass a json file with a url e.g

```
d3.json("https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/git/blobs/2e0e3b6305fa10c1a89d1dfd6478b1fe7bc19c1e?" + Math.random())
.on("progress", function() {
```

I would like to use this method by providing a contoller action url. I'm wondering if this is possible and if so what should the return type be? A json object or a file? I'm fairly new to grails and d3 so am having a bit of trouble

Comment: Have you tried `render as JSON` in `controller`?If your response can be represented as a `map` or `list`, then you can use `render myRespone as JSON` (`import grails.converter.JSON`).

Comment: Thanks..that approach worked..write this as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render as JSON` in controller should be helpful in this case.
If your response can be represented as a `map` or `list`, then use

```
import grails.converter.JSON

render myRespone as JSON
```

In case you need the response to be rendered in different formats, [`withFormat`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) can be used to suffice the purpose.